# Назначит слушателя для 50+ View

Tags: android, kotlin

у меня есть разметка фрагмента с 50+ ImageView. Сразу оговорюсь , я умею задавать слушателя через

```
val imageView: ImageView = view.findViewById(R.id.image_1)
    imageView.setOnClickListener(this)
```

Однако прописывать это для 50+ ImageView странно, задавать через разметку тоже не вариант, потому что это крайне сомнительная затея в целом и я слышал от многих хороших программистов, что лучше так не делать. Итак, как лучше повесить слушатель на все эти View?

Comment: В web, в таких случаях, навешивают на обертку всех этих элементов

Comment: Начнём с того, что пихать 50+ вью в одну разметку само по себе не хорошо - по возможности, лучше применить списочные элементы (`RecyclerView`, `ListView`, `GridView`, ...), а в них уже и обработка кликов строится пакетно.

Comment: в чем "странность"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чудес не бывает. Если у вас такой случай, что каждая картинка должна обрабатываться особым образом и их невозможно поместить в список, ибо таков дизайн - то ничего вам не остаётся кроме как вручную прописать каждой слушатель нажатий.

Т.к. вы не раскрыли деталей задачи, то далее лишь предположения.

1. Если картинки у вас логически одинаковые (список юзеров, например), то надо их в список поместить (RecyclerView) - там в одном месте на ImageView повесить слушатель нажатий и он ко всем применится.
2. Если картинки у вас логически одинаковые, но их невозможно поместить в список (например они все раскиданы дизайнером по экрану для красоты и свёрстаны соответственно), то можно написать метод, который рекурсивно пройдёт по контейнеру, где картинки находятся и им проставит слушатель нажатий. Если там ещё элементы есть, то можно их отсеять по к-л признаку, но это уже детали, которых вы не даёте.
3. Если у вас комбинация из п.1 и п.2, то и решением будет комбинирование решений - часть картинок в список, часть - рекурсивно обойти, часть - вручную назначить.